# $.ajax an't figure out why PHP not receiving POST data from $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

$.ajax successed,but in the php, I cannot get the data from ajax.

> Notice: Undefined index: email in..
>
> Notice: Undefined index: pass in ..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('click',"#bolero-user-login",function(){
     var email = $("#edit-name").val();
     var pass  = $("#edit-pass").val();
     // alert (email);
     $.ajax({
        url:"functions/php/login.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{ "email":email,"pass":pass},
        beforeSend: function () {
          
        },
        success:function(){
            alert("success");
            alert(email);
            $("#edit-name").val(" ");
            $("#edit-pass").val(" ");
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
             alert(XMLHttpRequest.readyState);
             alert(textStatus);
        },
     });
     return false;
 });

});
```

PHP:

```
<?php

define ("root",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
// echo root;
include root.'/maroon5/includes/dbh.php';
print_r($_REQUEST);

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pwd = $_POST['pass'];

?>
```

HERE is the pictures from firefox

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgWQn.jpg)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2vem.jpg)

[image: ajax success picture]
[image: PHP console picture]

Comment: `$email = $_GET['email'];` change this to 
`$email = $_POST['email'];`. You are sending a paramter by ` POST` request and trying to retrieve by `GET`.

Comment: Please dont add outbound links for images etc to the questions!

Comment: are you sure there are actually values being sent to the server? doesn't ajax remove fields with null values?

Comment: Typo in the code(from image link 1): _$conn = new sqli_connect();_ should be _$conn = mysqli_connect();_ | Unless of course, sqli_connect() is a class you created for some reason.

Comment: @Aj334 Thank you ,I had corrected this .But it still is "

    Notice: Undefined index: email in..

    Notice: Undefined index: pass in ..
"

Comment: @LTulip  add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` in your php file on top just after starting `<?php` and check . Also can you share full code of php. One more thing:- are you sure that ajax request is going fine and you don't have any error in your console?

Comment: @Rick ,Yes ,you can click the first image(I don't know why they become links,I just upload pictures) and the browser tells there are actual values.

Comment: crazy.. everything looks good from here.. does `var_dump($_REQUEST);` spit out anything? also what does the "Response" tab show in the console?

Comment: In success function receive the out put like this *success:function(result){
            alert(result);
         
        },*

Comment: @Rick I add `var_dump($_REQUEST);` ,after refresh , the browser says `array (size=0)
  empty`'

Comment: @AlivetoDie I add this `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` into php file.But there is no error tip ,just"undefined index email..."

Answer (score 0):

Change AJAX success into

```
success:function(data){             
    console.log(data);
    $("#edit-name").val(" ");
    $("#edit-pass").val(" ");
},
```

And AJAX page as well

```
<?php

define ("root",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
// echo root;
include root.'/maroon5/includes/dbh.php';
// print_r($_REQUEST);

$returnArr['email'] = $email;
$returnArr['pwd'] = $pwd;

echo  json_encode($returnArr);

?>
```

Comment: After I change this AJAX success and the php code as you say ,and refresh the broswer, php become "Notice: Undefined variable: email in .., Notice: Undefined variable: pwd in ..{"email":null,"pwd":null}"

Comment: Did you call ajax function in onclick event or document.ready?

Comment: Yes, I add a input(type = submit) element to my html , which ID is "bolero-user-login"

Comment: Then how your AJAX function getting called while you refresh the browser? Use $(document).on('click',"#bolero-user-login",function(){});